# How to check existing of application on device?

Tags: java, android

I have just made application which requires BarCode scanner on device. How can I programatically check existing of this application into device? I know package name for BC scanner.

Answer (score 1):

It is all documented on the zxing website. 
http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: I have found it already, but can't found how I can implement operation of checking.

Comment: Its all there on the wiki page and the linked code. Just read it.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest instead adding the scan functionality within your app, your app should never depend on other Apps to work.

Comment: Multiple apps working together is a core benefit of Android and as such you should not pull everything in and do it yourself.. e.g. think of dialer, sharing via twitter and so om displaying pdf and much more.. for scanning it depend imho

Comment: Btw Oscar I did not downvote your answer since I think it still applies as a valid answer.

Comment: @ManfredMoser I agree with stuff like the dialer, since that is part of the phone itself, but as you say for scanning it depends. Thank you for not downvoting.